# Missing Icons in MVC 5 project

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, summernote

I am working with an MVC 5 project. I have integrated [SummerNote](https://summernote.org/) into the project. Now the toolbar as you see in the above link has some icons. 
When I ran my project, it was working fine locally but when I deployed it couldn't find the icons. So since I don't fully understand how the whole thing works I fixed for the deployment by changing the paths in the summernote-bs3.css and summernote.css but then of course the local version broke.

The way I fixed it for deployment was I changed:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
src: url('~/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
src: url('~/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')     
format('embedded-opentype'), url('~/Content/fonts/glyphicons-     halflings-    
regular.woff') format('woff'), url('~/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-
regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url  ('~/Content/fonts/glyphicons-
halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');}
```

to:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
src: url('../Content/plugins/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
src: url('../Content/pluginsfonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') 
format('embedded-opentype'), url('../Content/plugins/fonts/glyphicons-
halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), 
url('../Content/plugins/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') 
format('truetype'), url('~/Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-
regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');}
```

Note that I changed **~/Content/fonts/** to **../Content/fonts/**. I also did the same thing for summernote.css.

The reason for it was that on my deployment I was seeing an attempt to download:

https://mysite.azurewebsites.com/plugins/~/content/fonts/.....

but it couldn't find it even though ~ means home which effectively is the same as ../ in this scenario.

So I am not so sure how to fix this issue. How are these paths work or where they are picked up from?

I appreciate your thoughts and help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after hours of trial, I figured out how the path to the fonts/styles gets added to the site's URL. In bundle.config:

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/**plugins**/summernoteStyles").Include(

The base that is in bold above gets added to the end of your site's domain. So I was getting:

https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/**plugins**/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

To fix it, I changed the bundle.config to look like this:

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~**/Content/plugins/summernote**/summernoteStyles").Include(

Maybe it will help someone else one day.